Удалить index.php из url
https://site.ru/index.php/news-3750

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^news-([^/]*)$ index.php?do=news&po=$1 [QSA]

Не понимаю, как исправить, заставить подобные url
https://site.ru/index.php/news-3750

перенаправлять на
https://site.ru/news-3750

Кажется все возможные варианты что в интернете есть, перепробовала, ни одно не спасает...
# Удаление index.php c конца
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/  [NC,OR]
# С wwww на без
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\..+ [NC,OR]
# Удал.повтр //         
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} // [NC,OR]
# С http на https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]


Я так думаю, для вас важна "зацепка" по шаблону вида /index.php/news-здесь цифры - просто по вашей фразе "подобные url" невозможно четко понять, что является для вас "подобным" - /index.php/news-здесь цифры или целиком /index.php/что-то здесь.
Поэтому, код ниже описывает rewrite для /index.php/news-здесь цифры.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php/news\-(\d{1,})$ /news-$1? [L]

Проверить работоспособность этого правила можно здесь.
Если требуется чуть другой паттерн, то, я думаю, для вас уже не составит труда переделать пример.

Все супер, работает если указать флаг R=301  RewriteRule ^index\.php/news\-(\d{1,})$ /news-$1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/  [NC,OR] Если на главной странице присутствует index, я также его удаляю. Но с правилом выше. Происходит какая та цикличная переадресация, браузер говорит.

Прикрепила свой ряд правил к вопросу, где сразу 5 правил и одна переадресация. Получается либо так,либо так. Возможно ли практичное правило придумать, для всех случаев? Не привязываться к конкретным символам в строке... То есть просто, если есть index.php в строке, удаляем.

Было бы очень здорово...

Лена, вы на ходу меняете условия в своем вопросе.  В моем ответе я предложил решение вопроса, который был актуален на тот момент. Сейчас у вас еще какие-то другие условия добавляются. Что самое главное: а) эти условия являются разными и независимыми б) общая формулировка уже еще больше запутывает - совершенно уже непонятно, что требуется (я даже закрыл глаза на index.php?do=news&po=$1 в вашем примере, потому что он вообще из другой оперы и не имел отношения к сути вопроса - вы определитесь изначально уж как-то)
